# phonegap: how to display the product without reload the list page

Tags: javascript, cordova

I hope i can get help with this...

So I'm using the owlCarousel to display my products in the carousel....

I fill the carousel from the HTML5 localstorage  and when i click on one item, the item is displayed on another html page...

the problem is that everytime I go back from the product detail page to the page with the carousel  the carousel get's reloaded ...

is there a posibility to show the product and when going back the previous page to stay the same ...  overlay or any other solution ?

I on the product detail page i display the product the same way as in the carousel ... from the localstorage ...

i hope you understand my question and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try using cookies? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: i dont know if you understand the question...
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/customJson.html

try to refresh the page and you will see that the carousel kinda "drops down" ... i have 3 carousels on the page ... and when I click on item and go back the page refreshes ... and starts from zero.. so i want to try to display the itam in another way so the page with the carousel stays the same ...

Comment: Cookies to store the carousel position then when you load the page use the cookies value to move the carousel to the correct position.

Comment: the bigger problem is the loading of the carousel...  i only show 20 items per carousel ...  so the current position is not a drama ...  i want to eliminate the loading ...